# Compile article excluding appendix (without commenting it out)

Tags: compiling, appendix

Consider a simple article:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

some text

\begin{appendix}

some text

\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to tell Latex ro compile the file as if there were no `appendix` section, that does not involve commenting it out? I have a very large appendix and commenting it out again and again is quite cumbersome.

Comment: You can use the `comment` package and add `\begin{comment}` before `\begin{appendix}` and `\end{comment}` after `\end{appendix}`. Slightly off-topic: `appendix` isn't an environment, you should replace `\begin{appendix}` by `\appendix` and remove the `\end{appendix}`.

Comment: Thank you Phelype, that is indeed a bit easier. Is there a way to do this with a single line at the header (using some package or defining a new command)? Something like `\ignoreappendix`?

Comment: `\renewenvironment{appendix}{\comment}{\endcomment}` with compination of `\usepackage{verbatim}` should work. (You could put this command just after your `\documentclass`, in order to find and comment out easier when you want the appendix printed)

Comment: If you put the appendix into a separate file you can use \include and possibly \includeonly  (depending on whether you want your labels and references to still work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by Phelype Oleinik, you could use the `comment` package.
This package also allows adding new comment environments, so you could make the `appendix` environment a comment, by adding

```
\excludecomment{appendix}
```

to the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\excludecomment{appendix}
\begin{document}

some text

\begin{appendix}

some text

\end{appendix}

\end{document}
```

This is a nice solution if you use an appendix environment, but in most cases `\appendix` is a command, no environment. So you would use `\appendix` instead of `\begin{appendix}` and there is no need for `\end{appendix}`.

Then, you can archive a similar effect by defining `\appendix` as `\end{document}`: LaTeX will stop when it encounters the `\appendix` and all further content is ignored:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\appendix{\end{document}}
\begin{document}

some text

\appendix

some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent answer Marcel, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just put

```
\end{document}
```

before the appendix.

Comment: This would also work, although it's a bit easier to comment/uncomment a single line as in Marcel's answer.

Comment: @https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/13294/gabriel It is only a single line in my answer.

Comment: Actually, you are right. I just have to comment/uncomment that line to add/ignore the appendix. I hadn't noticed that, sorry. I still prefer Marcel's answer because I can do that from the preamble, but this is nonetheless a great answer. Thank you!